# Standard approach for multi browser test execution in Selenium Jupiter

Tags: junit5, selenium-jupiter

I went through Selenium Jupiter manual and still cannot get the idea of how I can set multiple 
browsers in Selenium Jupiter to run every test in every browser.

Should use Test Template for that purpose?

Again I did not see an example of how can I do it in Selenium Jupiter?

p.s. An example with RemoteDrivers on Selenium Grid.

Here is my attempt to do it:

public class BaseTestWithRemoteDrivers {

```
@RegisterExtension
static SeleniumExtension extension = new SeleniumExtension();

@BeforeAll
public static void setupAll() {
    extension.getConfig().setSeleniumServerUrl("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
    Browser chrome = BrowserBuilder.chrome().build();
    Browser firefox = BrowserBuilder.firefox().build();
    extension.addBrowsers(chrome, firefox);
}

@Test
public void testWithBrowser(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}

@AfterAll
public static void tearDownAll(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Unfortunately, only the Chrome browser will open.

Upd: I also found that there is a message saying:

Browser list for context id is not found. Not sure how to set up Browsers List if it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I did not find multi browsers support except by explicitly putting the browsers type into mvn command like below:

> **mvn verify -Dtest=BaseTest
>
> -Dsel.jup.selenium.server.url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>
> -Dsel.jup.default.browser=chrome
>
> -Dsel.jup.default.version=80.0.3987.106**

```java
 @ExtendWith(SeleniumExtension.class)
    public class BaseTest {
    
        @Test
        public void testNumber1(RemoteWebDriver driver) throws {
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
      
        }
    
    
        @AfterAll()
        public static void tearDown(RemoteWebDriver driver) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

---

***Update:***

I figured out the way I can do it with Test Template too.

Below is the working example:

```java
public class MultiBrowserTestTemplate {

@RegisterExtension
static SeleniumExtension extension = new SeleniumExtension();

@BeforeAll
static void setup() {
    String browsersList = System.getProperty("prop.browsers.list");
    List<String> browsers = Arrays.asList(browsersList.split(","));
    if (browsers.contains("chrome")) {
        extension.addBrowsers(BrowserBuilder.chrome().version("80.0.3987.106").build());
    }
    if (browsers.contains("firefox")) {
        extension.addBrowsers(BrowserBuilder.firefox().version("73.0").build());
    }
}
}

public class MultiBrowserDemoTest extends MultiBrowserTestTemplate {

    @TestTemplate
    public void testInMultipleBrowsers(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        search.sendKeys("JUnit5 extensions");
        search.submit();
    }
```

And the maven command goes like this:

> **mvn verify -DMultiBrowserDemoTest
>
> -Dsel.jup.selenium.server.url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>
> -Dprop.browsers.list=chrome,firefox**